# link postback in reactJS and dotnet core using ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

We are building an application using React JS and dot net core and ant design. The developer instead of making links, he used

```
<p onClick={()=>dispatch(push("/"))}>home</p>
```

The reason provided is that this way page doesn't posts back, hence browsing between pages is much faster. I am not sure if this is a valid reason, I guess the right way might be:

```
<button type="link" onClick={()=>dispatch(push("/"))}>home</button>
```

OR

```
<a href="/">home</a>
```

Kindly advice what is the right way, since I am new to React and Ant Design.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no `type="link"` for `button` elements. But yes, the use of `p` is not a good approach. They should use `a` and cancel the default action. Or if they are using a router, they should use the provided link component for the router.

Comment: thanks @GabrielePetrioli, the 'type="link" is from antd just to render the button will different classes to appear as link

Comment: I see, then it should be `<Button>` with capital `B`. That is what threw me off, the lowercase refers to the browser `button` tag.

Comment: The `push("/")` implies usage of react-router. If that is so, they provide a `Link` and `NavLink` component for navigating.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli '<Button>' sorry about that. yes there are react-router. so you think using '<a> ' or '<Button>' is the right way? these tags helps in google crawlers also.

Comment: I think you should https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link, so `<Link to="/">home</Link>`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thank you, can u please post is as answer so that i can mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment discussion, since you are using the react-router, you can use the components, provided by the react-router library, such as [`Link`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) and [`NavLink`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink).

An equivalent use to your example would be

```
<Link to="/">home</Link>
```